# Detecting (another) sub-minipage inside an encapsulating minipage?

Tags: minipage, code

Is it possible to detect if a minipage is present in an encapsulating minipage?

Let me expand on that:

I have a float environment which, simplified, can be defined by `\begin{figure}[th]\begin{minipage}`, `\end{minipage}\end{figure}`.

I have another float environment `subfig` which can be reduced to a `subfigure` environment, from the subcation package, which is simply a minipage.

I'd like to automatically introduce a `\hfill` before the `\begin{subfigure}` if another subfigure is already in there. However I have no idea how to test that... Does anyone have?

If that interest anyone, here is the actual code (with subcaption package, and where [arg] are optional, and {arg} mandatory):

```
\makeatletter
%% figure environment
%% use example %%
%   \begin{fig}[fig:label]{figure caption}
%       figure...
%   \end{fig}
%% end example %%
\newsavebox\ContentFig
\newenvironment{fig}[2][@]
{%
    \if#1@
        \newcommand{\ContentCaptionLbl}{}%
    \else%
        \newcommand{\ContentCaptionLbl}{\label{#1}}%
    \fi%
    \noindent\ignorespaces%
    \begin{figure}[th]%
        \newcommand{\ContentCaption}{\unskip{#2}}%
        \begin{lrbox}{\ContentFig}%
            \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
            \centering%
}{%
            \end{minipage}%
        \end{lrbox}%
        \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\usebox\ContentFig}%
        \caption{\ContentCaption}\ContentCaptionLbl%
    \end{figure}%
    \global\let\ContentCaptionLbl\undefined%
    \global\let\ContentCaption\undefined%
}

%% sub-figure environment
%% use example %%
%   \begin{fig}[fig:figurelabel]{figure caption}
%       \begin{subfig}[fig:subfig1label]{sub-figure caption}[width]
%           figure1...
%       \end{subfig}
%       \begin{subfig}[fig:subfig2label]{sub-figure caption}[width]
%           figure2...
%       \end{subfig}
%   \end{fig}
%% end example %%
\newsavebox\ContentSubFig
\newenvironment{subfig}[1][@]{%                 % takes opt. arg for label
    \if#1@%
        \newcommand{\ContentSubCaptionLbl}{}%
    \else%
        \newcommand{\ContentSubCaptionLbl}{\label{#1}}%
    \fi%
    \begin{@subfig}
}{
    \end{@subfig}
    \global\let\ContentSubCaptionLbl\undefined%
}
\newenvironment{@subfig}[1]{%                   % takes mand. arg for caption
    \newcommand{\ContentSubCaption}{#1}%
    \begin{@@subfig}
}{
    \end{@@subfig}
    \global\let\ContentSubCaption\undefined%
}
\newenvironment{@@subfig}[1][@]{%               % takes opt. arg for width
    \newlength{\subfigwidth}%
    \if#1@%
        \setlength{\subfigwidth}{0.48\linewidth}%
    \else%
        \setlength{\subfigwidth}{#1}%
    \fi%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigwidth}%
        \begin{lrbox}{\ContentSubFig}%
            \centering%
}{%
        \end{lrbox}%
        \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\usebox\ContentSubFig}%
        \caption{\ContentSubCaption}\ContentSubCaptionLbl%
    \end{subfigure}%
    \global\let\subfigwidth\undefined%
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a friend, I have a solution: save the `\linewidth` length (plus a small quantity, to have strict inequalities) in the fig environment, and compare the current `\linewidth` length in the subfig environment with the saved one in order to add, or not,  the `\hfill`.

The code become:

```
\newenvironment{fig}[2][@]
{%
    \if#1@
        \newcommand{\ContentCaptionLbl}{}%
    \else%
        \newcommand{\ContentCaptionLbl}{\label{#1}}%
    \fi%
    \newcommand{\ContentCaption}{\unskip{#2}}%
    \newlength{\parentFigWidth}%                    % to automagically add \hfill in subfigs
    \setlength{\parentFigWidth}{\linewidth}%
    \addtolength{\parentFigWidth}{2pt}%
    \begin{@fig}%
}
{
    \end{@fig}%
    \global\let\parentFigWidth\undefined%
    \global\let\ContentCaption\undefined%
    \global\let\ContentCaptionLbl\undefined%
}
\newenvironment{@fig}[1][th]
{%
    \noindent\ignorespaces%
    \begin{figure}[#1]%
        \begin{lrbox}{\ContentFig}%
            \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
            \centering%
}{%
            \end{minipage}%
        \end{lrbox}%
        \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\usebox\ContentFig}%
        \caption{\ContentCaption}\ContentCaptionLbl%
    \end{figure}%
}

%% sub-figure environment
%% use example %%
%   \begin{fig}[fig:figurelabel]{figure caption}
%       \begin{subfig}[fig:subfig1label]{sub-figure caption}[width]
%           figure 1
%       \end{subfig}
%       \begin{subfig}[fig:subfig2label]{sub-figure caption}
%           figure 2
%       \end{subfig}
%   \end{fig}
%% end example %%
\newsavebox\ContentSubFig
\newenvironment{subfig}[1][@]{%             % takes opt. arg for label
    \if#1@%
        \newcommand{\ContentSubCaptionLbl}{}%
    \else%
        \newcommand{\ContentSubCaptionLbl}{\label{#1}}%
    \fi%
    \begin{@subfig}
}{
    \end{@subfig}
    \global\let\ContentSubCaptionLbl\undefined%
}
\newenvironment{@subfig}[1]{%               % takes mand. arg for caption
    \newcommand{\ContentSubCaption}{#1}%
    \begin{@@subfig}
}{
    \end{@@subfig}
    \global\let\ContentSubCaption\undefined%
}
\newenvironment{@@subfig}[1][@]{%           % takes opt. arg for width
    \newlength{\subfigwidth}%
    \if#1@%
        \setlength{\subfigwidth}{0.48\linewidth}%
    \else%
        \setlength{\subfigwidth}{#1}%
    \fi%
    \if\linewidth<\parentFigWidth%
        \hfill%
    \fi%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigwidth}%
        \begin{lrbox}{\ContentSubFig}%
            \centering%
}{%
        \end{lrbox}%
        \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\usebox\ContentSubFig}%
        \caption{\ContentSubCaption}\ContentSubCaptionLbl%
    \end{subfigure}%
    \global\let\subfigwidth\undefined%
}
```

(also added a position option in fig environment)